# Using the UserDict module of python

Tags: python, object

I am learning python from the book diveintopython .
Before asking this question, I have consulted the answers given [here](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/python/bugs/749658) and read the documentation given [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/userdict.html), but they don't clarify exactly what i want to know.

In the book, a class UserDict has been written like,

```
class UserDict:
    def __init__(self, dict=None):
        self.data = {}
        if dict is not None: self.update(dict)
```

next another class FileInfo has been mentioned,

```
class FileInfo(UserDict):
    "store file metadata"
     def __init__(self, filename=None):
         UserDict.__init__(self)
         self["name"] = filename
```

My question is an object of the UserDict class has an attribute **data** which is a dictionary. When i create an object of FileInfo class, the object inherits this but why is the object itself a dictionary rather than having its **data** attribute as a dictionary?

Please tell if there is something i have misunderstood here.

Answer (score 1):

There's more of the implementation of `UserDict` that you're not showing (otherwise it wouldn't have an `update` method for example)... Most likely the book is showing a piece of the [UserDict implementation in the standard library](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/UserDict.py#l1).

This class was probably very useful back in the days *before* a user could subclass *dict* directly.  Basically, it allowed a user to create objects which looked and behaved like dicts -- They could then tweak the behavior for a specific purpose (consider all of the dict subclasses provided in the [`collections` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html)).  These days, because you can subclass `dict` directly (or use the `collections.MutableMapping` ABC) to create your own dict-like classes, there's hardly ever a need for `UserDict` anymore -- It survives only to support legacy code.

---

Now as far as the implementation goes, since they couldn't subclass `dict` directly, they provided the same interface via ["composition"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition).  They could simply delegate the dictionaries methods to the underlying dict (`self.data`).  This way, they *know* that they have an object that looks like a `dict` in almost every way.  And, since it's built in pure python, a user could subclass it to tweak the behavior.

Comment: As you said in your answer, "it allowed a user to create objects which looked and behaved like dicts", why is the object itself not a dictionary , i.e, self ={} , rather self.data={}? that is my question

Comment: if you set `self = {}` inside the function (and you _can_), but that change doesn't propagate _out_ of the function...

Answer (score 0):

this is not directly supported now in Python 3.x

One workaround is to use the collection class and add the following:

`from collections import UserDict`